# font size 100 percent with an exception

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am building a responsive webpage and would like the font of my page set to 100% with the exception of the navigation text, which is to remain consistent. I thought targeting the nav font-size via media queries would do that trick, then I thought add important would work, but sadly, no luck.

```
@media (max-width: 950px) {
    body {font-size:95%;}

    nav {font-size:100% !important;}
}
```

Comment: Don't you have your percentages backwards? Shouldn't body be 100% and nav be 95%? Can you be a little more elaborate as to your desired effect.

Comment: I want every font in my webpage to resize according to the percentages I define in my media queries with the exception of the navigation font, which is to remain the same size (100%) no matter how the screen is resized. I could write down a rule for every single font in every single media query, but I don't think that's very efficient or good practice, so I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: What do you mean you want the nav text to remain consistent? Does that mean a specific size like 14px? Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want all of your fonts on the page to be 100% except for the `nav` elements you are setting up your percentages wrong. Also, unsure why you have this set in the media query.

In order to understand the example below you need to understand that since you have the `font-size` of body set to `150%`, by setting the `nav` `font-size` to `95%` you are now setting the `nav` `font-size` to 95% of 150%, which would be equivalent to 142.5%. Font sizes percentages are relative to their parents.

Here is what I suggest:

```css
#navContainer {
  font-size: 150%;
}

nav {
  font-size: 95%;
}

#standalone_Nav nav {
  font-size: 142.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navContainer">
  <div>This is body text at 150%</div>
  <nav>This is Nav Text at 95% of 150%</nav>
</div>

<div id="standalone_Nav">
  Standalone standard text
  <nav>Nav text set at 142.5%</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand this, now my navigation font works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Move `nav {font-size:100% !important;}` outside any media queries